# Install PIL egg to custom directory without root or PIP

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install PIL using Python2.6 to a custom directory (e.g. /home/my_dir/Python), as I do not have root access on my work's system. I'm able to get the executables  installed by running.

```
easy_install --prefix=/home/my_dir/Python Pillow
```

however the rest of the package does not install to the directory. I created manually /home/my_dir/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages, so that the package would install. The problem is that PIL already exists on our system's python interpreter under /usr/lib/python2.6, so when  I run the above command it pulls from the existing PIL egg and does not install the whole thing into my custom directory, only the executable files. Is there a way to install the egg itself into the custom directory without uninstalling the existing one?

Comment: Can you use virtualenv (venv)? It makes life a lot easier than such manual package management.

Comment: I do not. I tried installing it as well as pip using easy_install but I receive and error saying
    error: could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
same thing for virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution, for anyone who comes along this post. The following command will work.

```
easy_install --always-copy --prefix=/home/my_dir/Python/  package
```

The egg will be copied into /home/my_dir/Python/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/ and that will be used to install all the package files you want.